# What's the name of this puzzle, which consists of small cubes connected by elastics?

Tags: puzzle-identification

Does anyone knows the name of the puzzle showed in the image below?

[image: Starting position]

The objective is to mount a 3x3x3 cube such that all sides of this cube are equal. The small cubes of the image are linked by an elastic and some of them can rotate along this link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The puzzle that matches the one in the image is called The Snake cube.
http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/snakecube.htm